# XML to NSdictionary to plist

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, nsdictionary, nsxmlparser

Hi guys i have little weird problem. I am using a simple XML to NSDictionary converter
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/
 and but if  print the NSDictionary , i can see the text value for the node but if i store it in plist, text node will not have any string value. see attach images.[image: i can see the text node value when i print NSdictionary]

here is the plist screenshot.

[image]

here is the  code

```
NSURL * URL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"rss feed link "];
    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    NSString *testXMLString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Parse the XML into a dictionary
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:testXMLString error:&parseError];
    NSString * filepath = [self dataFilePathwithFilename:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TEST.plist"]];
  [xmlDictionary writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];


    // Print the dictionary
    NSLog(@"%@", xmlDictionary);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your `plist` files have empty values. You are just not accounting for the new line character in the highlight text in your first image (`"\n\thttp://wordpress.org/?v=3.0.1"`).

One easy way of verifying this would be to open it using a text editor. You will find that the values are there. You can also navigate to that field in the property list editor and press the down button.

**Replacing the newline characters**

Use [`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString%3awithString%3a) method to replace all newline characters with `@""`.

```
testXMLString = [testXMLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

**Better Trimming**

As such replacing tabs (`\t`) seems to render the string unreadable by the `XMLReader`. So to fix this, it would be easier the change the `XMLReader` code to insert trimmed values into the dictionary.

In the method `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:`, replace

```
[dictInProgress setObject:textInProgress forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];
```

with

```
NSString * trimmedString = [textInProgress stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n\t"]];
[dictInProgress setObject:trimmedString forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];
```

Comment: hey deepak how should i remove those new line character from the NSString *testXMLString before parsing it to NSdicntionary.

Comment: Hi deepak i tried filtering the string before parsing it to NSdictinoary but same characters are there in the text node. I think they get added when i parse the value from string to Nsdictionary. Is there a way that i can filter the whole dictionary and remove \n and \t characters from it

Comment: Traversing the dictionary and removing them would be complicated process. It would be correct to replace it in the string itself. Can I get the link so that I can try it myself?

Comment: Are you doing the same thing for `\t`'s as well? Use the same line above and replace `\n` with `\t`.

Comment: @Amrit updated the answer. There seems to be a better approach to do this.